# Clipboard history in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, clipboard, clipboarddata

Is there a plugin available in Eclipse that shows all recently copied items in clipboard like this one https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-2-clipboard-history for sublime editor

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[More Clipboard](https://github.com/mikhail-barg/moreclipboard) seems to roughly achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: there's an old enhancement request to build this functionality into eclipse. if anyone wants this to happen please vote here https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=48505