# Eclipse paste from clipboard history (keyboard shortcut)

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, copy-paste

I am using eclipse juno, I need to know if there is any keyboard shortcut for pasting some text from the copied clipboard history, I mean in JDeveloper there is a combination of keys <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> this will bring a popup showing all the earlier copied texts, then the user selects whatever text he wants to paste, is there anything similar in eclipse?

Comment: Good question. At-least are there any plugins to achieve this?

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK It is really annoying that eclipse doesn't have this feature built-in, I mean it is a really really useful feature. I think there should be some plugins that can do that.

Comment: A quick google search would have revealed this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160132/clipboard-history-in-eclipse
and this:
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pde-tools#clipboard-history

Comment: @MatF your comment should be an answer, and by the way post only the second link.

Comment: I think a 5sec google search is not worth to be an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes as @MatF said you can use MoreClipboard plugin. -1 to [PDE Tools Cliboard View](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pde-tools#clipboard-history) as it not brings up popup window to select old entries.

Also moreclipboard has the same short cut key as in Jdeveloper i.e <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Quick links:

- [Quick Guide](http://moreclipboard.sourceforge.net/docs/)
- [Donwload Link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/moreclipboard/)
- [Update site](http://moreclipboard.sourceforge.net/updates)